# SQL GROUP BY or JOIN

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I am using SQL 2008 and just cannot get this query to work.  I have a table with flight price details in it.  There are many rows for each day for each route and I want to return the lowest price per day for the route and also the DateAdded (the datetime that the row was added).  I am almost there as I seem to have managed to get the lowest price per day returned but I can't seem to get the correct dateadded to be returned.  The code below seems to work to return the lowest price per day but I think I need some sort of join to also return the DateAdded?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlightInfoLowestPricePerDay]
(
@AirportFrom    varchar(5),
@AirportTo      varchar(5)
)

AS
select  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TimeDeparture)) as FlightDate, MIN(Price) as MinPrice


from FlightInfo
where AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and AirportTo = @AirportTo
AND TimeDeparture > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))

Group By DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TimeDeparture))
Order by FlightDate ASC
```

I have tried things such as the code below but I do not fully understand joins yet so have been struggling for quite a while although I'm sure I'm missing something very simple!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlightInfoLowestPricePerDay]
(
@AirportFrom    varchar(5),
@AirportTo      varchar(5)
)

AS
select  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi1.TimeDeparture)) as FlightDate, MIN(fi1.Price)     as       MinPrice, fi2.DateAdded


from FlightInfo 
fi1 join FlightInfo fi2 on fi1.Price = fi2.Price
where fi1.AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and fi1.AirportTo = @AirportTo
AND fi1.TimeDeparture > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))

Group By DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi1.TimeDeparture))
Order by FlightDate ASC
```

Comment: Using your first query without joins I think you could just put DateAdded into an Aggregate function like `MAX(DateAdded)`

Answer (score 0):

Add fi2.DateAdded in Group By

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlightInfoLowestPricePerDay]
(
@AirportFrom    varchar(5),
@AirportTo      varchar(5)
)

AS
select  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi1.TimeDeparture)) as FlightDate, MIN(fi1.Price)     as       MinPrice, Cast(Convert(varchar(20),fi2.DateAdded,101) as datetime) DateAdded


from FlightInfo 
fi1 join FlightInfo fi2 on fi1.Price = fi2.Price
where fi1.AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and fi1.AirportTo = @AirportTo
AND fi1.TimeDeparture > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))

Group By DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi1.TimeDeparture)),Cast(Convert(varchar(20),fi2.DateAdded,101) as datetime)
Order by FlightDate ASC
```

Comment: This isn't working, it now brings back multiple rows per day instead of just the minprice row.  I just need the dateadded which is associated with the minprice

Comment: change fi2.DateAdded to Cast(Convert(varchar(20),fi2.DateAdded,101) as datetime)

Comment: No, now I am getting this:

Comment: FlightDate       MinPrice DateAdded
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-01 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-02 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-03 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-04 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-05 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-06 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-07 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-08 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-09 00:00:00.000
2013-03-24 00:00:00.000 280 2013-02-10 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 0):

OK I decided to simplify it a bit as I've wasted too much time on this already so now I am passing a specific date into the query and running the query multiple times to get the results I need:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FlightInfoLowestPriceDateAddedForSpecificDate]
(
@AirportFrom    varchar(5),
@AirportTo      varchar(5),
@Date           datetime
)

AS

select  top 1 *
from FlightInfo 

where AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and AirportTo = @AirportTo
AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TimeDeparture)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Date))

Order by Price asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use window function for this.  One way is with `row_number()`:

```
select flightDate, price
from (select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TimeDeparture)) as FlightDate, fi.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by airportFrom, airportTo, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, TimeDeparture)) order by price) as seqnum
      from FlightInfo fi
      where AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and AirportTo = @AirportTo and
            TimeDeparture > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
     ) fi
where seqnum = 1
```

If you are using more recent versions of SQL Server, then you can take advantage of the `date` data type:

```
select flightDate, price
from (select cast(TimeDeparture as date) as FlightDate, fi.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by airportFrom, airportTo, cast(TimeDeparture as date) order by price) as seqnum
      from FlightInfo fi
      where AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and AirportTo = @AirportTo and
            TimeDeparture > cast(getdate() as date)
     ) fi
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can two sub queries (one that gets the small prices per day and the second one the DateAdded)

```
SELECT  f1.FlightDate, f1.MinPrice, f2.DateAdded From  
(  
    SELECT  
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi1.TimeDeparture)) as FlightDate,
        MIN(fi1.Price) as MinPrice
    FROM FlightInfo fi1
    WHERE fi1.AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and fi1.AirportTo = @AirportTo
        AND fi1.TimeDeparture > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
    Group By 
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi1.TimeDeparture))
) f1
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, fi2.DateAdded)) AS DateAdded, 
        Price FROM FlightInfo fi2
    WHERE fi2.AirportFrom = @AirportFrom and fi2.AirportTo = @AirportTo
        AND fi2.TimeDeparture > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
) f2 ON f2.Price = f1.MinPrice
```